# Class in a list

Tags: c#, list, class

I understand that in C# a class is always passed by reference. However does this mean that when I store the said class in a List it is stored as a reference as well, or better said as a C# style "pointer" of sorts? Does this also mean that a list with N elements of the class will not take up as much memory N times the size of the class but only N times the size of the reference to the class?

Or am I just thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding the question correctly, but if you instantiate 10 `Foo`s (where `Foo` is some memory intensive type), then make 20 lists containing the same 10 `Foo`s, your memory usage does not change (neglecting the overhead of the `List`s).

Comment: You cannot store a _class_. You always store an _instance_ of a class, usually called an _object_.

Comment: @Asad Thank you, thats spot on to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically right.

If I create N elements of class T, and class T uses, say, 10 bytes, that takes on the order of 10*N memory.

If I store that in `List<T>`, we still have 10*N memory for the objects, plus N times the size of a C# reference and the `List` overhead.  If I store those same elements in two lists, I have the 10*N for the objects, plus 2*N for the references, and 2 times the list overhead.  They're pointing at the same underlying objects.